# Where to buy half tubes for outdoor games

Tags: sweden, outdoor-games

I saw this game on youtube where you need to make a ball travel a certain amount of space using some half tubes. I was wondering where you could buy these kind of tubes or how are they called in english since I am not a native speaker [image]

Comment: Is this an outdoor game?  Seems like one can just as well play it indoors, which makes it a bit of a "boat programming" question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a general game that can be played anywhere (indoors or outdoors), I don't think it's a good fit for The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry to hear, I just so the video outside so I just assumed this was an appropriate place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brightly coloured stuff pictured was probably sold for the purpose, unless it was painted for the players to use.

The most readily available material in the UK (and other bits of Europe I know, but the only time I've been to Sweden was 30 years ago) is guttering, as used to collect rainwater falling off roofs. This should be available from most places selling building or DIY materials. A good size for this would be the smaller type often used on garden sheds and similar small outbuildings.

Comment: The Swedish term is "[takränna](https://www.beijerbygg.se/privat/sv/produkter/tak/takavvattning/r%C3%A4nnor-r%C3%B6r/tak-h%C3%A4ngr%C3%A4nna)".

Comment: "hängränna" is also a common term for this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to buy these things buy I saw the video too and was impressed. So my friends and I made them from the usual plastic bottles. We cut it this way and it works. We used a table tennis ball too. It was interesting, but not for long. Can't recommend you buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I bought pvc pipe from a hardware store and cut it in half lengthwise with a hand saw to play this game. The game works best with one ball for every three pipe segments.